# Why x <- list() is.null(x) gives FALSE, whereas y <- c() is.null(y) gives TRUE?

Tags: r

```
x <- list()
is.null(x)
# [1] FALSE

y <- c()
is.null(y)
[1] TRUE
```

According to the definition of `NULL` in R, if any data object is `NULL`, then `is.null` will give `TRUE`, but why `x` is not `NULL`?

Answer (score 2):

I think the key here is to understand that `list` is a *vector type* in R. It should be obvious enough once you're past the R basics that you can have strings, numbers, booleans and integers in vectors that you can access with `[`.

That list are on equal footing as these other vectors may be a bit more surprising*.

Much like you can have a 0-length character vector instantiated by `character()`, then, we need a way to instantiate a 0-length list. `list()` is exactly the way to do so.

`NULL` by contrast is a placeholder for "nothing". It is not a vector. Therefore `is.null(list())` is `FALSE`.

As for `c()`, this comes down to what `c` is for and how it should behave with no input.

My preference is to think of "c" meaning *combine* -- it combines it's inputs in a "natural" way.

For 0 inputs, combining nothing gives nothing -- i.e., `NULL`.

Therefore `is.null(c())` is `TRUE`.

- PS, there are other built-in vector types as well, e.g. raw, complex, and expression.

Comment: I use `gtools:invalid()`. `gtools::invalid(c())` and  `gtools::invalid(list())` give `TRUE`. "test if a value is missing, empty or contains only NA and NULL values ".

Answer (score 1):

The output of functions is different as @TarJae said. This can be seen using `str()`:

```
x <- list() 
str(x) 

y <- c() 
str(y)
```

If you need empty (0-length) vectors you can use `numeric(0)` / `character(0)` instead. You can also investigate the following:

```
c(1)[-1] # creation of vector and removal of its members
# or
c('A')[-1]
```

you will get 0-length typed vectors:

```
numeric(0)
character(0)
```

So empty vector (`numeric(0)`) is not equivalent to `NULL`.

```
numeric(0)==c()
```

will return `logical(0)` as there is a comparison against of an object against `NULL`

Answer (score 1):

You should read about the help document of `NULL` first, by typing `?NULL`

> NULL can be indexed (see Extract) in just about any syntactically
> legal way: whether it makes sense or not, the result is always NULL.
> Objects with value NULL can be changed by replacement operators and
> will be coerced to the type of the right-hand side.
>
> NULL is also used as the empty pairlist: see the examples. Because
> pairlists are often promoted to lists, you may encounter NULL being
> promoted to an empty list.
>
> Objects with value NULL cannot have attributes as there is only one
> null object: attempts to assign them are either an error (attr) or
> promote the object to an empty list with attribute(s) (attributes and
> structure).

and also, in the examples provided by the manual, you can have better understanding

```
is.null(list())     # FALSE (on purpose!)
is.null(pairlist()) # TRUE
is.null(integer(0)) # FALSE
is.null(logical(0)) # FALSE
as.null(list(a = 1, b = "c"))
```